# How do I allow `multicols` environment to break across multiple frames? (beamer)

Tags: beamer, multicol, multicolumn

It does not seem that `multicols` environment can cross across pages. Is there an alternative to create multiple columns that are filled automatically (i.e., we just insert the items and the environment fills columns using its own algorithms) with the contents but can break frames if necessary?

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.7]{Long Lists}

    \begin{multicols}{2}

        \blindlistlist[3]{enumerate}

        \blindlistlist[3]{enumerate}

        \blindlistlist[3]{enumerate}

    \end{multicols}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: To quote the beamer user guide about `allowframebreaks`: "The use of this option is evil." The content of each slide should be carefully planed and not the result of some automatic column or page breaking.

Comment: As shown multiple times in the manual the author likes to indicate his personal opinion with quite strong wording. This quote is one such occasion. It is rather useless to argue about that and especially use them in technical discussions such as this one. There are various ways to make use of the combination of the two respective features with very good reasons that neither the author of any latex package nor we the stackexchange community are entitled to judge.